# Could a question be undeleted?

Tags: discussion

Let's consider a question is of extremely high quality and that the asker is already dead in real life.

Could the question be reopened or undeleted yet kept closed?

Comment: I'm not sure how a user being dead would matter. Is this a situation we're actually facing right now?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I just deleted all my awesome questions and erk-- *thud*

Answer (score 2):

A moderator could do it, but I'm not sure that we would if the owner originally deleted the question.

Comment: If, however, the OP was dead--dead as a parrot--then the owner's original intent would no longer matter... (divining the absolute state of their corporeal existence presents a separate and much more interesting problem).

Comment: I don't find it all that interesting, if the op deleted their content then I would respect the wishes of the dead and leave it deleted. The only interesting scenario I could see with is if a family member of the recently departed started deleting their content. Even then this does not seem to be a real issue.

Comment: For "interesting", read either "impossible" or "impractical." The comment was intended to highlight the absurdity of the premise...